# Нахождение совпадающих букв в двух строках

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу очень простенькую консольную программу на Python (данный язык программирования только начал изучать), возник вопрос.
Как реализовать это в коде? (см. ниже)

> Даны 2 небольших слова (без пробелов), нужно сравнить, совпадают ли
>   буквы в одном слове с буквами в другом. Например, даны слова
>   "password" и "pillow". Компьютер анализирует их и видит, что в обоих
>   словах есть буквы "p", "o" и "w". Тогда он осуществляет вывод в виде:
>   "В словах совпадают n букв", где n-количество совпадающих букв.

Пожалуйста помогите, думаю это не очень сложно реализовать, но я пока что не очень понимаю, как это сделать.
Желательно код представить в максимально простом виде (в очень очень простом)

Answer (score 8):

```
word1 = "password"
word2 = "pillow"
# приводим каждое из слов к множеству и находим пересечение этих множеств
common_letters = set(word1) & set(word2)
# получили множество букв, которые есть в обоих словах
# в данном случае это {'p', 'o', 'w'}
# выводим размер множества (т.е. количество совпадающих букв):
print(len(common_letters))
print(common_letters)  # просто выводим совпадающие буквы в виде множества
print(', '.join(common_letters))  # выводим буквы через запятую
```

Немного теории:

- [Множества в Python](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/mnozhestva-set-i-frozenset.html)
- [Множества в математике](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE), особенно обратить внимание на [бинарные операции с множествами](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE#%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8) (в данном ответе как раз используется пересечение множеств)

Comment: Как говорится краткость сестра таланта))

Comment: @insolor  нужно вивести не количество в формате (цифра) а эти елементы\

Comment: @NikitaChekalin, впрочем, добавил вывод самих букв. Но так как вы нигде не написали, какой вывод вам нужен, то вывожу как сам понял.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

str1 = 'word'
str2 =  'world'
counter = Counter(str1)
counter2 = Counter(str2)
counts = 
[(counter2[i] == counter[i]) for i in list(str1)]

print(sum(counts))
```

> `4`

Также посмотрите [руководство](https://python-scripts.com/import-collections) по модулю *[collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html)*

Comment: says Reinstate не помог

Comment: Во первых я @Victor says Reinstate Monica. Во вторых у меня работает.

Comment: @NikitaChekalin, напишите чем конкретно не подходит ответ?

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, [эта правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1054637/3) - это худшее что можно было сделать с циклом for.

Comment: @insolor Аргументируйте свое мнение ;)

Comment: Аргументирую правильным вариантом: `counts = [counter2[i] == counter[i] for i in list(str1)]`. Использование `append` внутри list comprehension - дикое извращение.